# Is it possible to make a substring out of a Guid in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring, guid, truncate

I have to truncate the first couple of digits out of a Guid on a table. Is it possible to do it only using a SQL script? Or I have to do it programatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the GUID stored as a string or a `uniqueidentifier`?  Seems like truncating it would make is much less "unique".  What the purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the direct question at hand (and assume the column's name is `foo`):

`foo` is uniqueidentifier:

```sql
SELECT substring(convert(nvarchar(50), foo), 3)
```

`foo` is simply a string:

```
SELECT substring(foo, 3)
```

*`3` is just an arbitrary starting offset to remove the first "few" characters.*

With that said, this sounds like of like an XY problem. If you're running into an issue where you feel you need to truncate the first few characters, it would be important to list that information in your question as well as what you've described sounds like an odd request. However, you're also entitled to have odd requests.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer was perfectly good. Another option is to use the wonderful `RIGHT` function. Assuming the Guid is a a uniqueidentifier, then it has 36 characters in it. Just use `RIGHT(theguid, 34)`, e.g.

```
declare @temp as uniqueidentifier = newid();
select right(@temp, 34);
```

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this? The solution works, and presents another way of thinking about the problem.